# Onclick event works as intended, but using addEventListener for keyup does not on JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a simple rock, paper, scissors javascript project. The problem I'm running into is that when I click an input button to submit a choice (taken from radio buttons for rock, paper or scissors) it works as intended, resetting the checked radio buttons and styles as to allow another selection to be made from scratch.

```
// Code to run when the user clicks the submit button
const submit = () => {
    // Check if the choice has been made
    if (!userChoice) {
        document.getElementById('played').textContent = (`
        Please make a choice`);
        document.getElementById('played').style.color = 'red';
        document.querySelector(".submit-choice").focus();
        // Check if there are still rounds left to be played
    } else if (roundNumber < roundsToPlay) {
        document.getElementById('played').style.color = '';
        // delete content on div
        document.getElementById('played').textContent = null;
        // get user choice
        userChoice = getUserChoice(userChoice);
        // get ai choice
        aiChoice = getComputerChoice();

        document.getElementById('played').innerHTML = (`${determineRoundWinner(userChoice,aiChoice)}`)
        updateState();
        // reset all buttons:
        if (document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked')) {
            document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked').checked = false;
        }
        resetStyles()
        userChoice = '';
    } else {
        if (gameFinished && userScore > aiScore) {
            document.getElementById('played').style.color = 'green';
            document.getElementById('played').innerHTML = (`The game ended ${userScore} for you and ${aiScore} for the AI.<br>CONGRATULATIONS! YOU WON!`);
        } else if (gameFinished && aiScore > userScore) {
            document.getElementById('played').style.color = 'red';
            document.getElementById('played').innerHTML = (`The game ended ${userScore} for you and ${aiScore} for the AI.<br>F, you've lost :(`);
        } else if (gameFinished) {
            document.getElementById('played').style.color = '';
            document.getElementById('played').innerHTML = (`The game ended ${userScore} for you and ${aiScore} for the AI.<br>ITS A TIE :O`)
        }
    }
    if (roundsToPlay > roundNumber) {
        document.getElementsByTagName(
            "legend"
        )[0].innerText = `What do you choose for round ${roundNumber + 1}?`;
    } else {
        gameFinished = true;
    }
}
```

The result of this function when ran from a onClick submit button works perfectly, the choice is made, the game state is updated accordingly and the styles get reset and the variable userChoice rolled back.

But when this exact same code gets runned from addEventListener it does not work:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    if (event.code !== 'Space') return;
    if (pressed) return;
    pressed = true;
    setStyle('.submit-choice', 'transform', 'scaleY(80%) translateY(1rem)')
})
document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    if (event.code !== 'Space') return;
    pressed = false;
    setStyle('.submit-choice', 'transform', '')
    submit();
})
```

I tried logging what happens inside of the eventListener, but after submit the variable userChoice is an empty string (as intended), but gets rolled back to the latest choice once the event ends (not intended). Same goes for the styles, they do get restarted for a very brief moment and afterwards the last choice gets highlighted again (not intended). This is the only not intended behavior, since the game does advance accordingly otherwise.

Why does this work with onClick perfectly and not with eventListener ? How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance, I'm struggling to learn this language and any help is much appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/joacopaz/fpd1L95a/3/

You can see the project here

Comment: How is that the exact same code? It's completely different from the code run in `submit()`.

Comment: Where is the `onClick` code that you're comparing with?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I've edited the post and added a JSFiddle of the page. You can see the onclick="submit()" for the button that says Smash your epic choice
<button class="submit-choice"  tabindex="6" type="submit" onclick="submit()">. In JSFiddle the spacebar doesnt work, but if you copy this to visual studio it works in live server. You can see the effect the spacebar has (it works but doesnt reset styles or checkbox values)